# CSS: Need a float:right button to appear at the bottom when content overflows

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, less

How to handle scenario where button **floats** to the right and when the left content overflows, the button comes to a new line behaving like a **block** element?
[image]

```css
.div-wrapper button { float: right; }
```

```html
 <div class="div-wrapper"> 
  <span> Some data here....(when this text overflows, make button come to the bottom left) </span> 
  <button> 
     Redeem
   </button>
</div>
```

I have tried to use flex-wrap: wrap; etc. But none of them seems to be working as expected:

Comment: UX police here: Folks are going to have a hard time predicting where those buttons are going to be.

Comment: You're right! So where do you suggest for the button to be when data overflows?

Comment: Use a flexbox. Seriously. Just use a flexbox for such layouts. Floats are only "the right approach" if you have text and images that should _flow_ around each other. For layouting elements: use the appropriate display property. In this case here: flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case  `flex-wrap: wrap;` should work. Not need `float:right` to button

```css
.div-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrapper"> 
  <span> Some data here....(when this text overflows, make button come to the bottom left) </span> 
  <button> 
     Redeem
   </button>
</div>
```